# How to do a conditionnal insert in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know how I can insert something in my database **ONLY IF** it matches certain conditions. I do not want to insert anything with unauthorized values in it.

In fact, I would like to do something like this : (let's say I want to insert a new order only if it comes from a certain type of clients)

```sql
    INSERT INTO orders
    (columns names)
    VALUES (values)
    WHERE orders.client_id IN (SELECT id FROM clients WHERE condition...)
```

(I know it's not possible, that's for the example.)

I tried this :

```sql
    INSERT INTO orders
    (columns names)
    VALUES (values);
    DELETE orders
    WHERE orders.client_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM clients WHERE condition...)
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

It seems to do the trick. But I can't believe this is a good solution.

So my question is : **Is there a way to do this properly, and in *only one* request ?**

(I found a lot of post on subjects more or less similar to this one, but most of them have answers with an INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... statement that I fail to understand and *seems* not working in my case.)

Comment: Why is this question tagged `php`?

Comment: I would: 1) initiate a transaction, 2) then perform a simple `INSERT`, 3) then make all the checks and if they all pass, 4) then and only then I would commit the transaction.

Comment: @arkascha It's a mistake, nothing more :)

Comment: If you construct that query in a client application then just don't send it, if the values are not appropriate. If this about some data integrity constraint then use a trigger.

Comment: @stickybit The thing is I develop an API where (roughly) sellers can register orders for their clients. But I want to check they create orders for their clients ONLY, and not for a client of another seller. I don't want to check this condition before insert in order to minimize the request number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could trick it with a `SELECT` from a mock subquery that will allow you to use a where clause.

```
     INSERT INTO orders
     (client_id, ...)
     SELECT client_id, ...
     FROM (SELECT 'your_value' AS client_id, ...) foo
     WHERE client_id IN (SELECT id FROM clients WHERE condition...);
```

Comment: OP should note that this will silently insert nothing in the event that the predicate is not satisfied.  That may be fine.  Anyway, they may nevertheless be able to test whether a row was added by looking at the resulting number of rows affected.

Comment: That's a good point. While I don't think it would cause any problems, this solution should be tested thoroughly before being put into a production environment. MySQL has some interesting and rather unpredictable quirks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
INSERT INTO orders (columns names)
    SELECT . . .
    FROM clients
    WHERE condition;
```

I am not seeing why you need a subquery.

Comment: I just try that and it seems it works too. However I had to add a GROUP BY statement behind the WHERE clause, without it, the request inserts as many orders as there are clients matching the WHERE clause. Thanks.